# Equivalent condition of Hausdorff

Tags: general-topology

[image]

This claim is from Ulrich Gortz and Torsten Wedhorn's  Algebraic Geometry I. First I think there are some errors that (ii) and (iii) should be

For every topological space $Y$ and every continuous map $f : Y\to X$ its graph $\{(y,f(y)); y\in Y\}$ is closed in $Y\times X$.

For every topological space $Y$ and any two continuous maps $f, g : Y\to X$ the kernel $\{y\in Y ; f(y) = g(y)\}$ is closed in $Y$.

But even for this, I wonder if this is correct? For example, I know that if $X$ is Hausdorff, then for every topological space $Y$ and every continuous map $f : Y\to X$ its graph $\{(y,f(y)); y\in Y\}$ is closed in $Y\times X$, but is the converse true?

Similarly, I wonder if for every topological space $Y$ and any two continuous maps $f, g : Y\to X$ the kernel $\{y\in Y ; f(y) = g(y)\}$ is closed in $Y$ we can conclude that $X$ is Hausdorff?

Comment: $X,Y$ should also be interchanged in $(iii)$ so that the indicated 'kernel' makes sense as a subset of the domain.

Comment: @Mirko are you sure? I think William's answer works perfectly well with my correction

Comment: @Mirko the Hausdorff space needs to be the image for the graph statement do $Y\times X$ is correct. And the kernel is a subspace of $Y$ indeed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hausdorff implies (i).
If (x,y) not in the diagonal, exists open U,V that separate x,y.
Since U,V are disjoint, open U×V misses the diagonal.
Thusly the complement of the diagonal is open.

(i) implies (iii).
f×g:Y×Y -> X×X, (x,y) -> (f(x), g(x)) is continuous.
{ y : f(y) = g(y) } = (f×g)$^{-1}$({ (x,y) : x = y }
is the inverse image of a closed set by a continuous function, hence closed.

(iii) implies (ii).  (ii) is a special case of (ii).
(ii) implies (i).  (i) is a special case of (i).
(i) implies Hausdorff.
Proof is left for the enjoyment of the diligent reader,